# Replace vsetivli to vsetvli in LLVM, RISC-V

Tags: assembly, vectorization, llvm, intrinsics, riscv

I have a binary generated with help of LLVM from [Halide](https://github.com/halide/Halide) project. to keep the story short, the binary uses RVV 1.0 while my hardware is AllWinner D1 C906 is RVV 0.7 so some intrinsics not supported and I'm looking for an option to determine and remove/replace unsupported RVV 1.0 intrinsics in LLVM source code.

First of them is `vsetivli` which seems to me can be replaced to older `vsetvli`. The only question is how to do it?

```
1dfae:       cd027057                vsetivli        zero,4,e32,m1,ta,ma
```

[RVV 0.7 spec](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec/blob/0a24d0f61b5cd3f1f9265e8c40ab211daa865ede/v-spec.adoc)
[RVV 1.0 spec](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec/blob/3570f998903f00352552b670f1f7b7334f0a144a/v-spec.adoc)

([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/RISCV/comments/v1dvww/comment/ialzm2q/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

Comment: It might be a lot easier to recompile with an older compiler version that still supported the 0.7 version of the specification.

Comment: This is not an option due LLVM is already a compiler and they keep RVV support on 1.0 spec with no switches. If you mean older LLVM I will try, thanks. However, some actual features might be missed.

Comment: Yes, correct.  Try an older LLVM version or perhaps an older gcc version.

Comment: I use standard risc-v cross-compliler from Ubuntu 20.04 for LLVM/Halide and XuanTie toolchain https://github.com/T-head-Semi/xuantie-gnu-toolchain for the binary. For non-vectorized code everything is fine. Let me try older LLVM or https://github.com/T-head-Semi/llvm-project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried workaround `vsetivli` by some rough patch at `selectVLOp` (actual for LLVM 13.0 - 16.0). Now `vsetvli` is added by the else condition.

```
--- a/llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCVISelDAGToDAG.cpp
+++ b/llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCVISelDAGToDAG.cpp
@@ -1503,10 +1503,11 @@ bool RISCVDAGToDAGISel::selectZExti32(SDValue N, SDValue &Val) {
 // allows us to choose betwen VSETIVLI or VSETVLI later.
 bool RISCVDAGToDAGISel::selectVLOp(SDValue N, SDValue &VL) {
   auto *C = dyn_cast<ConstantSDNode>(N);
-  if (C && isUInt<5>(C->getZExtValue()))
-    VL = CurDAG->getTargetConstant(C->getZExtValue(), SDLoc(N),
-                                   N->getValueType(0));
-  else
+  // if (C && isUInt<5>(C->getZExtValue())) {
+  //   VL = CurDAG->getTargetConstant(C->getZExtValue(), SDLoc(N),
+  //                                  N->getValueType(0));
+  // }
+  // else
     VL = N;
 
   return true;
```

Comment: Just for a note, I were able to port a limited algorithm to RVV 0.7.1 by manual replacement of illegal instructions from RVV 1.0 to their predecessors (like `vlbu.v` instead of `vle8.v`). See https://github.com/halide/Halide/discussions/7252#discussioncomment-4979482